# List a complete column family using consistency quorum

Tags: cassandra

I am a faily recent user of Cassandra. I went through the basics, setting up my schemas and plugging a java application to a database. Didn't run into any major problem putting together a sample app. Now I started messing with down nodes and I'm stuck on the listing of the content of a column family.

I have 5 nodes, 127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2, 127.0.0.3, 127.0.0.4, 127.0.0.5, and the datastax.com schema "demo", except that I used a replication_factor of 3 instead of one (I keeped the SimpleStrategy). I have 3 rows in the "users" column family (key "jsmith", "yomama" and "bobbyjo").

Now I take down a node, either 2, 3 or 5 (I didn't touch 1 yet since it's my only seed), and I connect to 4, processing the following CQL query :

```
select Key, full_name, email, state, gender, birth_year from users;
```

AS expected, it gives me my 3 rows even with 1 node missing. So the next step is to ask for a consistent result.

```
select Key, full_name, email, state, gender, birth_year from users USING CONSISTENCY QUORUM ;
```

It fails. I couldn't figure it out. Having a replication factor of 3, I'm supposed to get away with a downed node. Now just for fun, I added a generic condition as follows

```
select Key, full_name, email, state, gender, birth_year from users USING CONSISTENCY QUORUM where KEY IN ('jsmith', 'bobbyjo', 'yomama') ;
```

And now I get my 3 rows using consistency quorum with one node down. Is it normal that I can't browse a complete column family using quorum with a downed node, but I can list all the rows anyway if I give cassandra their keys ?

Answer (score 1):

A couple of questions:

1. Did you start with 5 nodes and an RF of 3 or did you grow the cluster to 5?
2. Did you try issuing the select statement which initially failed after issuing the one that worked? (If it works, you just saw read-repair in action - you may not have issued a 'nodetool repair' depending on your answer to #1 above).
3. What version of Apache Cassandra, btw?

Comment: 1. Created 5 fresh nodes, created the sample, then turned off one node.
2. Yes, tried many times in different order.
3. 1.0 RC2. The 1.0.0 was not out wet last week, it was released yesterday.

Comment: If this is still happening with 1.0.1 (1.0.2 is under vote and due out in the next 24 hours) please open a Jira issue with the details above. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA

Comment: OK, I'll retest it on a real release ASAP and submit it as an issue through the proper channel if it's still blocking. I innitialy put it on stack overflow first because I was not sure if it was realy a sort of bug or just a feature I didn't understood right.